# Calling a function 2 or more degrees below

Tags: java, c#, oop, methods, call

I'm sure this is a classic case in OOP and the answer will be straightforward for most programmers, but I don't seem to find the explanation anywhere. 
Suppose I have a method belonging to a class A instantiated in a class B, like in the following code :

```
class A
{
    public void foo() {/*do something*/}
}       

class B
{
    public A objectA;

    public B()
    {
        objectA = new A();
    }

    public void call()
    {
        objectA.foo();
    }
}
```

Suppose now that I have a third class C that instantiates class B (which in turn instantiates class A with the code above) :

```
class C
{
    public C()
   {
       objectB = new B();
   }
}
```

What is the best way to call function foo() from class C (if any):

```
objectB.call();
```

or else

```
objectB.objectA.foo();
```

I feel that the first option might be the right answer in terms of modularity, but it seems redundant if the class B never has to call foo().  **Is there a good answer here or is this whole pattern inherently flawed ?  And if it is, what design principle does it violate and what are the workarounds?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter): "Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers", or in another formulation, "Only talk to your immediate friends".   Thus, the second option above is in strict violation of this principle.

That being said, I guess having the need to fill multiple accessors methods in intermediate classes for the sole purpose of seeing the distant class is not a sign of great design.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, `objectA` should not be public in the first place. Considering it as a state of class B, I would say that only B and its subclasses should be able to use it directly, so I would prefer the first option.

However, if it is really public, then it means external classes are considered having enough information to manipulate it directly, or that they can do it without altering the state of B instances. In that case, which must be rare, the second option is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If objectA is truly public, then either is acceptable.  It would be more common for objectA to be protected, and there not available to C